# Can I create a POST endpoint which accepts a JSON for which I do not know the name of the exact name of properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am looking to pass in a data object (taken from the ag-grid getFilterModel() method) with the following structure:

```
{
property1: {
          type: "string",
          values: ["test1", "test2"]
          }
property2: ... (etc.)
...
}
```

I do not know the explicit names of the properties, but for purpose of my endpoint I do not need to. Currently, I have something working, but this is with a hardcoded object. Here I explicitly define the properties in the HTTP-POST method.

Post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void testAPI(MyTestObject test){

/// do something

}
```

MyTestObject.cs:

```
public class MyTestObject{
    public GenericProperty heights {get; set;} ;

    public GenericProperty weights {get; set;} ; 

   // ^all the properties will be of genericProperty type how can I avoid explicitly listing them?


}
```

Generic Property.cs

```
public class GenericProperty{
     public string type {get; set;} ;

     public string[] values { get; set;}
}
```

The Json object will only have properties of type GenericProperty, is there a better way to define the MyTestObject without explicity listing the names of the properties?

Comment: What version of asp.net and .net?

Comment: Target Framework is .NET framework 4.6.1

Comment: Maybe declare the expected request body parameter as `Dictionary<string, object>`? In the function body, you should get the value as: `test.TryGetValue("<key>", out object value)`. This is safe method to avoid getting the issue if the key is not found.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work unfortunately

Comment: I feel like we can use a JSON serializer for this, but I am not sure how we can serialize without knowing the variable names.